# How to keep the Users Login

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am testing an ionic2 application on an android phone and I was wondering how to keep user login into the application and log out only after the user clicks on log out button? because every time I close the app I have to login in again

Comment: Have you tried anything? also, consider using sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Kishore's solution, you can store the logged in state in `localstorage`. You can set the localstorage like this:

inside your component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class StateService {
    constructor(private _storage: Storage) { }

    public login(): void {
        this._storage.set('loggedIn', true);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        this._storage.remove('loggedIn');
    }
}
```

Once the user has logged in, call the `login()` method which will store the state as true. When the user logs out, call the `logout()` method.

Inside your app.component.ts

```
constructor() {
    this._storage.get('loggedIn').then((value:any) => {
        if(value) {
            //navigate to whatever page
        } else {
            //navigate to log in
        }
    });
}
```

This is the basic principal.

Comment: Thank you, both of you  that really  help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Store user token or status in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedInStatus", "active");
```

After logout

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedInStatus", "");
```

Comment: This is a very basic answer, but that's the principal of what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling the server side you can create a access token. If the login is for app only. Use local storage to save a value and delete when user clicks on logout.